# loop round a PHP array and display all values

Tags: php

I have this PHP code that displays values in an array:

```
$header->from[0]->mailbox . "@" . $header->from[0]->host;
```

whats the best way to loop round to get `[1], [2], [3]`, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it through a [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop like this:

```
foreach ($header->from as $from){
    echo $from->mailbox . "@" . $from->host;
}
```

If you want to process the first element outside the loop, then you can use [`array_shift`](http://php.net/array_shift):

```
$first_from = array_shift($header->from);
$first_from->mailbox . "@" . $first_from->host;
foreach ($header->from as $from){
    echo $from->mailbox . "@" . $from->host;
}
```

Comment: + add a link to `foreach` in the docs for educational purposes.

Comment: is it possible to do what i have in my question with [0] then put all the others in a loop?

Comment: Yes, you can always access the array via bracket notation as in your question.

Comment: but i don't want the [0] value to display in my loop

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Maybe you should update your question.